# For loop inside map React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, dictionary, for-loop

### Description

So I have an array like this:

```
const CategoriesList = [
    {nameNL:'bakkerij', 
     nameFR:'boulangerie', 
     nameEN:'bakery', 
     nameDE:'Bäckerei', 
     categories: [
        {nameNL:'bakkerij', nameFR:'boulangerie', nameEN:'bakery', nameDE:'Bäckerei'},
        {nameNL:'bier', nameFR:'la bière', nameEN:'beer', nameDE:'Bier'},
    ]},
]
```

And I can easily map all my items. However; inside that map function I want to loop between the **categories array** inside the **categorieslist**. I have tried to do this but apparently I can't use a for loop inside my map.

### Question

How can I loop objects inside a map function.

### What I have

```
 {CategoriesList.map(({nameNL, nameFR, nameEN, nameDE, categories}, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className='flxRow'>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameNL}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameFR}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameEN}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameDE}</div>
            {
                for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { 
                    console.log(categories[i].name)
                }
            }
        </div>  
)})}
```

Comment: you use another `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const CategoriesList = [
{nameNL:'bakkerij', 
 nameFR:'boulangerie', 
 nameEN:'bakery', 
 nameDE:'Bäckerei', 
 categories: [
    {nameNL:'bakkerij', nameFR:'boulangerie', nameEN:'bakery', nameDE:'Bäckerei'},
    {nameNL:'bier', nameFR:'la bière', nameEN:'beer', nameDE:'Bier'},
]},
```

]

```
const result = CategoriesList.map(item => {
 return item.categories.map(item2 => {
   return (
    console.log(item2.nameNL));
  })
 });
```

Working:

https://codepen.io/anildelhi/pen/YdPmvL?editors=1111

Answer (score 4):

You can use another `map`:

```
 {CategoriesList.map(({nameNL, nameFR, nameEN, nameDE, categories}, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className='flxRow'>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameNL}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameFR}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameEN}</div>
            <div className={['flxCell', 'flxCol2'].join(' ')}>{nameDE}</div>
            {
                categories.map(category => ...)
            }
        </div>  
)})}
```

I recommend reading about [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) as well

Comment: That did it; thank you! & I understand what you mean about the keys part.

Answer (score 0):

```
news API has JSON data like:-

{data: [
{
Description: "dummy description.",thumbnail_img_path: "images.jpg",video_path: "Z9xBo001urjkd"
},
{
Description: "dummy desc2.",thumbnail_img_path: "images-thumnail-1.jpg",video_path: "jklbtt2of8"
}]}
```

```
{news.map((item,i) => (   
                    
                    <div key={i}>
                    {
                        item.data.map((data, index) => (  //console.log(data.Description)) )                        
                        <div key={index}>
                            <div className="panel video-thumbnail" >
                            <img className="img-fluid"  src={data.thumbnail_img_path} alt="thum1" ytid={data.video_path} />
                            <div className="img-overlay">
                            <a href="#"><img src="../micro-assets/img/video-play.svg" alt="vplay" /></a>
                             </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>                       
                ))                                  
        }
```